# Clicking on tags in global search results is broken

Tags: bug, tags, stackexchange.com, 404-not-found, global-search

If you search for something on "all sites" (using the searchbox at the top of https://stackexchange.com, you'll reach the search results, e.g.  https://stackexchange.com/search?q=foo+bar+baz.

If you click directly on a tag on that page, e.g.

> [image: example for tag on global search page]

You get 404 Page Not Found error, e.g. https://stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology

---

## Steps to reproduce

1. Go to https://stackexchange.com and enter e.g. "keyforge" into the
   "Search all sites" field.
2. Arrive at https://stackexchange.com/search?q=keyforge
3. Click on the "keyforge" tag below a search entry.
4. Reach https://stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyforge (404 page
   not found)

## Expected behaviour

Reach https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyforge

## System Info

Happens in both Firefox and Vivaldi browsers on Windows 10.

Comment: Was about to make a post about this, but am glad to see somebody else spotted it as well. Kind of surprise that there weren't any replies though...

Comment: I didn't notice this and ask [another similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311224/3834)

Comment: I contacted support about this bug and got this: "Generally, the best way to get possible bugs seen is to post it on [our network's Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com), which hosts questions and issues about the Q&A software. That way, other users and our developers can vet the problem and discuss any solutions or other potential issues." So here I am...

Comment: This also occurs in chat, for example [Winter Bash 2018](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86686/winter-bash-2018-edition) where currently the Tags (upper right): [davids](http://stackexchange.com/tags/davids/info), (`http://stackexchange.com/tags/davids/info`, different URL than your example), [hats](http://stackexchange.com/tags/hats/info) and [secrets](http://stackexchange.com/tags/secrets/info) also *panda*.

Comment: This still needs to be fixed one year later.

Comment: it seems that in search results, it doesn't use the proper url for the tag ( for ex:  `stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/TAGNAME` instead of `thequestionsite/questions/tagged/TAGNAME`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed now, the tag links are working correctly again:

[image]

See [Send users to the correct site's tagged questions from the SE search results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335499/295232).