# The tags at Stack Exchange search page are not linked properly

Tags: bug, tags

Try [this page](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=general+relativity), for example.

And click on any one of the tags, it will result in a **page not found** error.

Comment: Related [New global search doesn't like tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308076/357396).

Comment: @NogShine that bug is already fixed right? So this is a different issue

Comment: it seems that in search results, it doesn't use the proper url for the tag ( for ex: `stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/TAGNAME` instead of `thequestionsite/questions/tagged/TAGNAME`)