# Send users to the correct site's tagged questions from the SE search results

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, stack-exchange, global-search

In the search results of `stackexchange.com/search?q=*`, allow people to click on a tag and go to that website with the tag page open.

For example, https://stackexchange.com/search?q=regex shows me this:

> [image: search results of regex on SE search]

But clicking on the hovered-on tag takes me to https://stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expressions and the panda.

Instead, it should take me to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expressions

The math.SE URL is already there in

```
/#question-summary-608993 > div.summary > div.started.fr > a
#question-summary-608993 > div.hot-question-site-icon > a
```

Comment: @adam I think it should have been an FR. But still, is there some update worth knowing?

Comment: It's definitely a bug, IMO. We fixed something similar recently... and this is probably the same thing in a different place. I'll try to take a look next week.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been fixed and the fix is live in production. Thanks for the report!